# Serial bluetooth disconnect detection c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bluetooth

How to detect if bluetooth device disconnected on windows?

Here is what I tried:

```
//return true if there is a connection
bool works()
{
    //portcom(handle to virtual serial port) and dcb are already initialised
    if(!GetCommState(portcom, &dcb)) return 0; 
    return SetCommState(portcom, &dcb);
}
```

But it only checks whether the port **exists** and it exists(because bluetooth ports aren't closed at all). So this doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check if the bluetooth is connected by **enumerating the bluetooth devices**.

[bluetooth api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothfindfirstdevice)

Use `BluetoothFindFirstDevice` and `BluetoothFindNextDevice` to enumerate devices, and determine whether Bluetooth is connected through the `fConnected` parameter in the `BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO_STRUCT` structure.

> ```
> typedef struct _BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO {
>   DWORD             dwSize;
>   BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS Address;
>   ULONG             ulClassofDevice;
>   BOOL              fConnected;
>   BOOL              fRemembered;
>   BOOL              fAuthenticated;
>   SYSTEMTIME        stLastSeen;
>   SYSTEMTIME        stLastUsed;
>   WCHAR             szName[BLUETOOTH_MAX_NAME_SIZE];
> } BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO_STRUCT;
> ```